# Contar los registros de una tabla pivot laravel

Tags: laravel

Como puedo **contar** los registros de una tabla dinámica, tengo la tabla `libros` y la tabla `materias` ya están relacionadas con la pivot `assigned_materias` me gustaría poder obtener cuantos registros hay por materia.

¿Saben de alguna forma?

Les dejo las tablas

**`libros`**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**`materias`**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**`assigned_materias`**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Publica también tus modelos, para que no te den respuestas como las de Aaron Gutiérrez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una manera simple de lograr lo que propones, va de la siguiente manera según la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

> ### Contando Modelos Relacionados
>
> Si desea contar el número de resultados de una relación sin cargarlos en realidad, puede usar el
>   método `withCount`, que colocará una columna `{relation} _count` en
>   sus modelos resultantes. Por ejemplo:
>
> ```php
> $posts = App\Post::withCount('comments')->get();
>
> foreach ($posts as $post) {
>     echo $post->comments_count;
> }
> ```

Entonces, asumiendo que tienes en Laravel tus modelos `Libro` y `Materia` definidos al igual que la relación que los une (en el modelo `Materia` existe el método `libros()`), aplicando a tu caso va así:

```php
$materias = App\Materia::withCount('libros')->get();
```

De este modo, tendrás una columna adicional `libros_count` que te indicará cuantos elementos hay por cada materia.

```php
foreach ($materias as $materia) {
    echo $materia->libros_count;
}
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta